# Segmentation fault and operator overloading

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, operator-keyword

Consider the following code:

```
bool Queue::operator+=(int value) {
    std::cout << "Appending the value " << value;
    std::cout << " by using operator overloading." << std::endl;

    // in the actual code: q->append(value);

    return false;
}

int main() {
    Queue *q = new Queue();
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        q+=6;
    }
    q->append(6);
    delete q;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I have way more code in the actual implementation, but here is the main problem:

I try to use operator overloading as an append function which adds an element to a `Queue` object.
The main functionality works with the function `Queue::append`. Anyways, I compiled this code and the `+=` operator overload compiles without errors. But the program crashes anyway.

When debugging it seems that whenever I use the `Queue` object `q` (for instance just the destructor or another function like `Queue::append`) *after* using the overloading, I get a **segmentation fault**.

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Clearly in this example, the overloading consists of an output and returning a `bool`.

Comment: I think you meant `(*q)+=6;`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Such a stupid mistake...I am kind of new to C++ and completely disregarded that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`q` is declared as a **pointer** to `Queue`.

The expression `q += 6` does *not* use the operator overload you have declared, it uses the standard operator for pointer arithmetics, and results in the pointer address being added to.

After the `for` loop, `q` does not point to the `Queue` object anymore and accessing it results in a segmentation fault.

To access the object `q` points to, you have to *dereference* the pointer, e.g. `*q`.